# Force capitalized first letter in search bar in ionic

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a ion-searchbar in my ionic4 project which default capitalizes the first letter (The shift-arrow on the iOS keyboard is solid). This is as expected, but when I submit the form and programmatically clears the value and sets focus:

```
this.searchbar.value = '';
this.searchbar.setFocus();
```

The shift-key is not longer solid and the first letter is **not** automatically uppercased.
How do I force the first letter to be automatically uppercased?

[image: Solid shift key]

I've tried using `autocapitalize='sentences'` (and the other values) on the ion-searchbar element, but that has no effect.
I've also tried to use javascript to automatically uppercase the first letter, but that was a very hacky and laggy solution. I've also tried to wrap it in a form element and used .reset() on the form, but that didn't solve it either.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with `autocapitalize="sentences"` on Android and it works fine even after clearing the value and set the focus programmatically.

```html
<ion-searchbar autocapitalize="sentences" #searchbar></ion-searchbar>
```

```js
@ViewChild('searchbar', { static: false }) searchbar: any;

cancel() {
  this.searchbar.value = '';
  this.searchbar.setFocus()
}
```

Perhaps the issue is only with iOS.

There is an [opened issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19827) on this matter at github. I suggest that you add a comment on that issue (if it's not whom opened it).

Comment: Thanks for trying it on Android. Are you able to try it on a iOS simulator as well? I'm the creator of that issue and since theres no response on their github Im trying my luck here.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no iOS device at the moment. I can only confirm its working on Android. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

try using `autocapitalize='true'`. It works with ion-text-area. Hope this will help

Comment: I know, but this is an issue on ion-searchbar which I use